# Django - ValueError: "strftime format ends with raw %" when DATE_INPUT_FORMATS and TIME_INPUT_FORMATS are set?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-settings, strftime

In Django I have form that is using the SplitDateTimeField which is set to have an initial value as shown below. When try view the template containing the form I get ValueError: "strftime format ends with raw %."

```
# forms.py

class DiscountForm(Form):
    title = CharField(widget=TextInput(), required=True)
    description = CharField(widget=Textarea(), required=True)
    fineprint = CharField(widget=Textarea(), required=True)
    start = SplitDateTimeField(
        input_date_formats='%m/%d/%Y',
        input_time_formats='%I:%M %p',
        initial= lambda: dt.datetime.now(),
        required=True
    )
    end = SplitDateTimeField(
        input_date_formats='%m/%d/%Y',
        input_time_formats='%I:%M %p',
        initial= lambda: dt.datetime.now() + dt.timedelta(days=30),
        required=True
    )
    limit = IntegerField(min_value=0, initial=0, required=True)

# relevant in settings.py 

USE_I18N = False
USE_L10N = False
USE_TZ = True

DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p')
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%m/%d/%Y')
TIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%I:%M %p')
```

Here is my traceback: http://dpaste.org/y55eV/

Any guidance is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Which line is exactly throwing the exception?

Comment: in my template when I try to load the "start" form field by doing:   {{ form.start }}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments `input_date_formats` and `input_time_formats` need to be lists or tuples, not strings (see [SplitDateTimeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.SplitDateTimeField) in documentation). The error may be caused that it is now iterating over characters instead of multiple input formats.

Try changing the code to the following:

```
start = SplitDateTimeField(
    input_date_formats=('%m/%d/%Y',),
    input_time_formats=('%I:%M %p',),
    initial= lambda: dt.datetime.now(),
    required=True
)
end = SplitDateTimeField(
    input_date_formats=('%m/%d/%Y',),
    input_time_formats=('%I:%M %p',),
    initial= lambda: dt.datetime.now() + dt.timedelta(days=30),
    required=True
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I actually already tried it! However I added the comma after the strings in the input format variables in settings.py. That did it.

Comment: Yes, the comma turns it into a tuple. Just adding `(` and `)` won't do because then it is still a string.